# Linux command to get distribution information

Tags: linux, unix, console

I want a common linux command i.e, command which can be run on any linux distribution to get its information. I have tried using **lsb_release** command. But for Red Hat there occurs error saying that "Command not found". **Is there any common command to get distro info.**

Comment: uname -a / uname -r ?

Comment: `cat /etc/*release*`

Answer (score 1):

Use this one for knowing the distribution version

```
$ cat /etc/issue
```